# Dynamic in the immediate window causes 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder' is not defined or imported error

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dynamic, immediate-window

If I use `dynamic` in the immediate window of Visual Studio I get an error

> Predefined type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder' is not defined or imported

How can I fix that?

Comment: I know your question has been asked long ago, but please check if my answer addresses the issue ... helping others having this issue too.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You should add reference to Microsoft.CSharp library in the selected project or in the startup project. And your project should reference .NET Framework 4 or higher.

[MSDN about immediate window context:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f177hahy(v=vs.80).aspx)

> When establishing the context for design time expression evaluation,
>   Visual Studio references the currently selected project in Solution
>   Explorer. If no project is selected in Solution Explorer, Visual
>   Studio attempts to evaluate the function against the startup project.
>   If the function cannot be evaluated in the current context, you will
>   receive an error message.

Comment: How do I do that? I'm using the 'immediate window'

Comment: You use immediate window in environment of some project. You should add reference to this project.

Comment: This is applicable also to debug watch windows. I had a solution with a startup project that did *not* reference Microsoft.CSharp, but referenced another project that *did*. Watch windows would throw the "binder not defined or imported" exception. Added a reference to Microsoft.CSharp on the **startup** project and all was well.

Comment: Referencing it in the currently selected project does not seem to work. I am having the same issue with System.Data, which is referenced, but cannot be found by the immediate window. Probably that only works during a debugging session? I'm using it to call a static method without starting a debugging session.

Answer (score 21):

Two things are important. Check the following:

1. That your project properties are referencing **.NET Framework 4 or higher** (if that is not the case, change it: Right click on the project, select the "Properties..." menu item, then select as target framework ".NET Framework 4" (or higher))
2. That you have added the **"Microsoft.CSharp" assembly** as reference (note that step 1., which requires to re-load the project, must be done before you can do that)

Afterwards you can use the `dynamic` type. The reference needs to be added in the selected project or in the startup project in order to become available in the immediate window's scope.

---

**Note:** [Here](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/c-programming/working-with-the-dynamic-type-in-c/?utm_source=simpletalkdotnet&utm_medium=pubemail&utm_content=20181127-slota1&utm_term=simpletalkmain) I found a nice article about **dynamics** in C#, how it works and what you can do with it.

Comment: Up voted, was hung up on unit test project not having that "Microsoft.CSharp" assembly referenced

Answer (score 8):

1. Go to project->add reference.
2. select assemblies from the side bar and Framework
3. check Microsoft.CSharp

Happy coding!

Comment: dont forget to click Ok

Answer (score 3):

Namespace:  Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder

Assembly:  Microsoft.CSharp (in Microsoft.CSharp.dll)

Example
http://stepbystepdotnet.wordpress.com/2012/08/06/predefined-type-microsoft-csharp-runtimebinder-binder-is-not-defined-or-importedtestproject1/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.runtimebinder.binder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.runtimebinder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx